# Что будет если в качестве родителя окна, задать само окно?

Tags: delphi

Что будет если в качестве родителя окна, задать само окно?

Comment: Статус ошибки будет.

Answer (score 1):

Ничего хорошего не выйдет, в Windows иерархическая система окон.
Тем более, что стандартными средствами вы это не сделаете - в функции `SetParent` в VCL стоит проверка:

```
if FParent <> AParent then
begin
  if AParent = Self then
    raise EInvalidOperation.CreateRes(@SControlParentSetToSelf);
  ..
```